# How can I get the value of a sibling input element?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do here is simply update my cart for my e-commerce website. To do so I need to confirm the quantity of the product with my "check button". So far I've managed to go over through all elements "check buttons", however now I'm troubled with accessing the input's value.

[image]

```
<div class="plus-minus-input">
        <span class="minus" data-action="remove" data-pack={{ item.product.pack }}>&#8722;</span>
        <input class="quantity" type="number" id="{{item.product.id}}" value="{{item.quantity}}"/>
        <span class="plus" data-action="add" data-pack={{ item.product.pack }}>&#43;</span>
        <span class="update-cart check" id="{{item.product.id}}">&#10004;</span>
</div>
```

...

```
checkBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("update-cart");

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBtns.length; i++){
        checkBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var productId = $(this).attr("data-productId");
            var action = $(this).attr("data-action");

            var parentDiv = $(this).parentNode;
            var inputVal = parseInt(parentDiv.childNodes[1].dataset.value);
            var pack = parseInt(this.dataset.pack);
...
```

Comment: Protip: Your "buttons" should actually be button elements.

Comment: One recommendation is if you are going to use Jquery, use jquery. You are combining vanilla javascript with jquery and jquery does do a few of those things.

Comment: You are mixing jQuery and vanilla JavaScript. Try to write code using only one of those and maybe you fix something.

Comment: Just use Vanilla JavaScript for your task.

Comment: I'm not sure 'dataset' should be in `parentDiv.childNodes[1].dataset.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` doesn't mean anything since you're not in a jQuery event handler. The simplest fix is to rectify that:

```
$(checkBtns[i]).click(function() { ... }
```

Then you have access to the clicked element in jQuery and can do this:

```
const inputVal = parseInt( $(this).siblings('.quantity').val() );
```

If you'd prefer to purge your life of jQuery (great in its day, not really necessary anymore), convert to this:

```
const parentDiv = e.target.parentNode;
const inputVal = parseInt(parentDiv.childNodes[1].dataset.value);
```

However, referring to elements by their order in your page is a fragile approach. If your layout changes it breaks. Instead, get the element by class:

```
const inputVal = parseInt(parentDiv.getElementByClassName('quantity')[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, when you use `this.dataset.pack`, `this` refers to `span.update-cart` which does not have a "pack" property.

Comment: Good comment, but what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

`<element>.dataset.value` won't be defined because value does not have the `data-` prefix. [MDN on dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

```js
const an_input = document.getElementById('an_input');

console.log(an_input.dataset.value);
console.log(an_input.value);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="an_input" value="3" />
```

Depending on your development environment / targeted browsers you may be able to use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

```js
const checkBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("update-cart");

for (var i = 0; i < checkBtns.length; i++){
  checkBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const input = e.target.closest('.plus-minus-input').querySelector('.quantity');
    console.log(Number(input.value));
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="plus-minus-input">
  <input class="quantity" type="number" id="{{item.product.id}}" value="{{item.quantity}}"/>
  <span class="update-cart check" id="{{item.product.id}}">&#10004;</span>
</div>
```

Using closest should insulate you from changes that would make it so that `.plus-minus-input` was no longer the direct parent of the check button. (For example wrapping the button in a div for layout reasons or what have you.)